# Monitoring software for diskspace on windows servers

Tags: windows, monitoring, disk-space-utilization, graphical-user-interface

I'm looking for a lightweight solution to monitor diskspace on windows servers and sent the report to a monitor server that presents the data in a nice gui. The server software can be linux or windows. But all the servers beeing monitored is windows.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer `nagios` for monitoring services. 
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-windows.html